# How to detect if the current instance of visual studio is active when writing a VS2012 addin?

Tags: events, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I want to be able to detect when the current instance of visual studio is active or in active, but searching through the available *hookable* events in the `_applicationObject.Events.` collection has not given me any clues. I can see when a window within the application is activated/deactivated with `_applicationObject.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated`, but this is not going to help. I want to know when the who application is active, not just a document or window.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the DTE.MainWindow.HWnd handle and use the Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Windows.Application.Current.Deactivated and Activated events to monitor when Visual Studio becomes active.

Comment: I will investigate that too. Thank you.